# Kingdom Hearts Timeline

Tags: kingdom-hearts-series

I recently started playing the Kingdom Hearts series (for the first time - I realise this is a little delayed) and am kind of confused at the sheer number of games there are and the amount of platforms they are available on.

Could someone provide me with a SPOILER FREE timeline in which the games take place (im sure this information is out there some where - I'm just cautious to look it up because i've already ruined a few bits of the story for myself trying to do so).

Also am I right in saying that on Kingdom Hearts, Kingdom Hearts 2 and the upcoming Kingdom Hearts 3 (Dream Drop Distance) are the only games that are part of the 'CORE' story?

Comment: Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance is *not* Kingdom Hearts III. KHIII will be a separate game. KH:3D is, however, going to tie into KHIII. This is a difficult question to answer, as the timeline in KH is, frankly, wonky as hell. Do you want just a chronological order in which the games take place?

Comment: That would be helpful, and perhaps an indication as to how relevant the game is to the overall story ? And thanks for the clarification regarding Dream Drop Distance.

Comment: Relevance is pretty subjective. I'm not sure how you'd measure that. They all have elements which tie into the overarching story and will, in general, enrich your play experience. I'm a big KH fan, and I try to consume all the lore, but even the biggest fans admit that it's become *incredibly* convoluted. :/ This is pretty much what always happens when Squeenix goes nuts with a story. :P

Comment: Yeah that's true about the subjectiveness, silly thing to ask really. The chronological order would certainly be helpful to point me in the right direction though.

Comment: I'll include a blurb about my opinion/experience with the games and when I played them to see if that helps a bit. :)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As of May 2nd, 2016, this is the chronological order in which the games take place. Credit goes to the Kingdom Hearts Wikia [Timeline article](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_%28series%29/Timeline). I'll link to the each of the games on the wiki for reference, but if you haven't played them, I'd recommend **not** clicking these links.

I'm going to divide this into 2 parts: chronological order in which the events in the stories/games occurred and a recommended playing order in order to *understand* the stories (as best as the KH storyline as a whole can be understood at least... it's... confusing).

### Chronological Order

1. *[Kingdom Hearts (Unchained) χ](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_%CF%87)* (Web Browser, Mobile) is the [prequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_%CF%87) to the *Kingdom Hearts* series as a whole, set 100 years before the events of *Kingdom Hearts*.
2. *[Kingdom Hearts: Birth by Sleep](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_Birth_by_Sleep)* (Playstation Portable) comes next in the timelines, excluding portions of its secret ending, Blank Points.
3. *[Kingdom Hearts](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_%28game%29)* (Playstation 2) aka *KH1*.

   - *[Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_358/2_Days)* (Nintendo DS, pronounced "three-five-eight days over two"). Days 1-24 take place at the same time as the finale of *Kingdom Hearts*.
4. *[Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts:_Chain_of_Memories)* (Game Boy Advance) aka KH:CoM. Since been rereleased as *[Kingdom Hearts Re:Chain of Memories](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_Re:Chain_of_Memories)* for PS2.

   - Days 25-27 of *KH:358/2* take place at the same time as *Chain of Memories*.
5. While not a separate game, days 28-358 of *KH:358/2* take place here in the timeline
6. *[Kingdom Hearts II](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_II)* (PS2) aka *KH2*.
7. *[Kingdom Hearts coded](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_coded)*. Takes place between the ending of *KH2* and *KH2*'s epilogue. This was released as a mobile phone puzzle game in Japan only. It's since been rereleased for the NA and EU territories as *[Kingdom Hearts Re:coded](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_Re:coded)* on Nintendo DS.
8. *[Blank Points](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Blank_Points)*. This is Birth By Sleep's secret ending. It goes from the end of BBS to some time after *[Signs of What's Next](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Signs_of_What%27s_Next)*, the secret ending of *Kingdom Hearts Re:coded*. The secret ending apparently has spoilers for *Birth by Sleep*, which is why the final episode for *Re:coded* wasn't released until after *Birth by Sleep*.
9. *[Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_3D:_Dream_Drop_Distance)* (Nintendo 3DS) It's set after the events of *Kingdom Hearts Re:coded.*
10. *[Kingdom Hearts III](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_III)* (Officially announced for Playstation 4 and Xbox One). Officially in development. We may still end up with more games in between before it is released.

So, that was slightly confusing. You may also have heard of the various *Final Mix* versions of the games. These are enhanced re-releases of the game that have additional content in them.  These versions were previously only released in Japan as explained below are being released in the NA/EU regions in HD Remixes.

### Recommended Playing Order (Pre-September 2013. See Alternate Order as of 2014 below)

1. ***Kingdom Hearts*** (PS2). Obviously. This is where you'll get the very basis of the story and the heart (no pun intended) of the conflicts. The first "main" game in the story.
2. ***Kingdom Hearts Re:Chain of Memories*** (PS2, only available for Japan and NA). Alternatively, you could play the original GBA version, which was 2D gameplay, but the PS2 rerelease is full 3D, like KH1 and 2, and also has voice-acted FMVs. It uses a card/deck system for fighting, which is different from the action RPG stylings of 1 and 2, but I still found it quite fun.
3. ***Kingdom Hearts II*** (PS2). The second "main" game in the story. You pretty much have to play this in order to understand the stories of the prequels/sequels/sidequels/whatever.
4. ***Kingdom Hearts 358/2*** (Nintendo DS). Considering the heavy tie-ins with the two main games and *CoM*, it's best to play this one after them. It's generally considered the weakest game, both story and gameplay-wise by the fanbase, as its plot twist is kind of... weird, but if you want to know everything in lore, I wouldn't really consider it a waste of time, though of course, your mileage may vary. Probably the most skippable if you just want to read a wiki entry on its plot.
5. ***Kingdom Hearts: Birth by Sleep*** (PSP). This is a prequel, with different characters than the main game (mostly), and is, in my opinion, a *must* play. Aside from a lot of important story elements, the gameplay is simply fantastic (though I haven't completed yet due to gaming ADD). Despite it being a prequel to the series, I would not advise starting with it, as many of the references and tie-ins to the other games' plots would simply not register.
6. ***Kingdom Hearts Re:coded*** (Nintendo DS). Though it takes place during KH2's epilogue, because of its secret ending heavily tying into Birth by Sleep's, it's recommended to play this one after that game. I haven't gotten my hands on this one yet, as it was only released in January 2011.
7. ***Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance*** (Nintendo 3DS). Taking place after Re:coded, this is where it fits in.

---

As of July 9, 2014 only Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 Remix has been released but Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 Remix has been announced for release in Oct 2, 2014 (JP), Dec 2, 2014 (NA), and Dec 5, 2014 (EU).

***[Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_HD_1.5_ReMIX)*** contains Kingdom Hearts 1 Final Mix (Previously exclusive to Japan), Kingdom Hearts Re: Chain of Memories, and ONLY the cutscenes from Kingdom Hearts 358/2

***[Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_HD_2.5_ReMIX)*** contains Kingdom Jearts 2 Final Mix (Previously exclusive to Japan), Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep Final Mix (Previusly exclusive to Japan), and ONLY the cutscenes from Kingdom Hearts Re:coded

I have not heard of any plans on re-releasing Dream Drop Distance on another platform just yet so you will still need a 3ds.

### Alternate Playing Order involving the HD Remixes

1. ***Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX*** (PS3) Play Kingdom Hearts 1 Final Mix
2. ***Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX*** (PS3) Play Kingdom Hearts Re: Chain of Memories
3. ***Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX*** (PS3) Play Kingdom Hearts II Final Mix.
4. ***Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX*** (PS3) Watch Kingdom Hearts 358/2 cutscenes
5. ***Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX*** (PS3) Play Birth By Sleep Final Mix.
6. ***Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX*** (PS3) Watch Kingdom Hearts Re:coded cutscenes.
7. ***Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance*** (Nintendo 3DS).

(?. ***Kingdom Hearts III*** (PS4) No release date announced yet. And no games announced between Dream Drop Distance and it's release although still possible.)

With the re-releases you now can play all of Kingdom Hearts up to but not including KH3 on 2 systems (the PS3 and 3DS). When KH3 comes out it will be 3 (PS3, (PS4 or Xbox One) and the 3DS).

Comment: And here I was writing a quick answer, wondering why you'd been acting like you were going to post something and hadn't... :)

Comment: @Shinrai Haha, yeah, this took me a while to write up, in between cross-referencing the wiki to make sure I had releases in proper order and writing out advice. I'm a pretty big KH nerd, so I wanted to be thorough!

Comment: Seriously wish I could give this more than a single upvote. Awesome answer :D

Comment: I don't own a PSP, and don't really plan to get one - is not playing BBS but playing the rest going to wreck the story or confuse me any?

Comment: @Ashley As I stated, I haven't completely finished BBS yet or played Re:coded (agh, so many games!), but I'd highly recommend reading the wiki summary for BBS in your case. It'll (likely) add more to your play experience if you care about the story, as it fleshes out the universe more and has events that happened pre-KH1. Some would argue that the more you know about the story, the more confused you get, so YMMV!

Answer (score 2):

I recommend playing them in order of release, and in my opinion they're ALL significant; however, chronologically they look something like this.

```
Kingdom Hearts: Birth by Sleep (be aware, the epilogue takes place after KH2)
Kingdom Hearts
Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories 
(remade as Kingdom Hearts RE: Chain of Memories for the PS2)
Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days (this actually starts during the events of Kingdom Hearts, but ends just before KH2)
Kingdom Hearts II
Kingdom Hearts coded (only available on Japanese cell phones) 
(remade as Kingdom Hearts Re:coded for the DS)
```

The upcoming Dream Drop Distance seems to go at the end of this list.

EDIT: I wouldn't recommend playing 358/2 Days before KH2, even though it finishes first - it spoils a few very major plot points in KH2.

Comment: True about KH:358/2 Days, should not play it before KH II.

Comment: Why the downvote (a year after the fact, to boot)?

Answer (score 1):

Heres the time line:

1. Kingdom Hearts X Chi
2. Kingdom Hearts Unchained X Chi
3. Kingdom Hearts Back Cover (not entirely known most likely going on During kingdom hearts unchained X Chi or kingdom hearts X Chi)
4. Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep
5. Kingdom hearts 1
6. Kingdom Hearts 358/2 days (day 1 is before Chain of memories starts when Xion appears Sora's story in Chain of memories is over)
7. Kingdom hearts Chain of memories
8. Kingdom hearts 358/2 days (day 71 and after) is after chain of memories
9. Kingdom Hearts 2
10. Kingdom Hearts Dream Drop Distance
11. Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep 0.2 A Fragmentary passage
12. Kingdom Hearts 3

Answer (score -1):

### Kingdom Hearts Chronology in 2015

---

#### Sorted by story events

1. [Kingdom Hearts X](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_%CF%87)

   > Kingdom Hearts X (chi) is a Kingdom Hearts game that is exclusive to
   >   PC browsers. The game is free to play, but includes additional
   >   purchasable items.
   >   The game is re-released as Kingdom Hearts Unchained χ in Japan on September 3rd, 2015.

[image: Kingdom Hearts X Logo]

2. [Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_Birth_by_Sleep)

   > Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep is a Kingdom Hearts prequel for the Sony
   >   Playstation Portable (PSP). It was released in Japan on January 9,
   >   2010, September 7, 2010 in North America, and September 10, 2010 in
   >   Europe

[image: Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep Logo]

3. [Kingdom Hearts](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_(game))

   > Kingdom Hearts is the first game in the Kingdom Hearts series directed
   >   by Tetsuya Nomura. Revolving around a fourteen-year old boy named
   >   Sora, it details his adventures after his homeworld is destroyed by
   >   sinister creatures known as the Heartless, and his attempts to restore
   >   his world and reunite with his friends.

[image: Kingdom Hearts Logo]

4. [Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_358/2_Days) **begins during events at the end of Kingdom Hearts**

   > Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days (read "Kingdom Hearts Three-Five-Eight Days
   >   over Two") is an RPG developed by Square Enix for the Nintendo DS,
   >   with aid from h.a.n.d. It focuses on the life of Roxas between the end
   >   of Kingdom Hearts and the beginning of Kingdom Hearts II, exploring
   >   the time from Roxas's creation until his confrontation with Riku that
   >   leads to his placement in the Simulated Twilight Town.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days Logo]

5. [Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts:_Chain_of_Memories)

   > Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories is a Game Boy Advance sequel to
   >   Kingdom Hearts. It was published by Square Enix and developed by
   >   Jupiter, and was released in 2004.
   >
   > - **Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days** runs **concurrently** with events of Kingdom
   >     Hearts: Chain of Memories **but ends later**.

[image: Kingdom Hearts: Chain of Memories Logo]

6. [Kingdom Hearts II](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_II)

   > Kingdom Hearts II is the sequel to Kingdom Hearts and Kingdom Hearts:
   >   Chain of Memories, and like the two previous games, focuses on Sora
   >   and his friends' continued battle against the Darkness. It also offers
   >   a number of improvements over the original with many new features,
   >   most notably Sora's Drive Form function, an improved camera, and
   >   in-battle options called Reaction Commands.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 2 Logo]

7. [Kingdom Hearts coded](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_coded)

   > Kingdom Hearts coded is a game in the Kingdom Hearts series that was
   >   released on the mobile phone as a puzzle game using 3D backgrounds. It
   >   focuses on King Mickey and Sora, depicting the events that transpired
   >   prior to the end of Kingdom Hearts II; the game is also deeply linked
   >   with Kingdom Hearts Birth by Sleep.

[image: Kingdom Hearts coded Logo]

8. [Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_3D:_Dream_Drop_Distance)

   > Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop Distance (previously known as Kingdom
   >   Hearts 3D) is a game in the Kingdom Hearts series released on the
   >   Nintendo 3DS hand-held system. It was released on March 29, 2012 in
   >   Japan, July 31, 2012 in US and Canada, July 20, 2012 in Europe, and
   >   July 26th in Australia.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 3D Logo]

9. [Kingdom Hearts III](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_III)

   > One of the next installments in the Kingdom Hearts series is currently
   >   called Kingdom Hearts III. It was officially revealed at E3 2013 via a
   >   trailer, alongside the announcement it would be released for the
   >   PlayStation 4 and the Xbox One.

[image: Kingdom Hearts 3 Logo]

### Remakes

1. [Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_-HD_1.5_ReMIX-)

   > Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX is an HD collection of two games
   >   from the Kingdom Hearts series. It features **Kingdom Hearts Final Mix**,
   >   **Kingdom Hearts Re:Chain of Memories**, and a full **cutscene collection**
   >   from **Kingdom Hearts: 358/2 Days** for Sony's PlayStation 3 platform.
   >   Both games have **remastered HD graphics** and Trophy support and the
   >   cutscenes from 358/2 Days have been remade in HD.

[image: Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 Logo]

2. [Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_HD_2.5_ReMIX)

   > Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 ReMIX is an HD remaster compilation of the
   >   Kingdom Hearts series and follow-up to Kingdom Hearts HD 1.5 ReMIX. It
   >   includes full HD remasters of Kingdom Hearts II Final Mix and Kingdom
   >   Hearts Birth by Sleep Final Mix. It also includes a collection of
   >   cutscenes from Kingdom Hearts Re:coded.

[image: Kingdom Hearts HD 2.5 Logo]

3. [Kingdom Hearts HD 2.8 Final Chapter Prologue](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Kingdom_Hearts_HD_2.8_Final_Chapter_Prologue)

   > Upcoming remake bundle including Kingdom Hearts 3D: Dream Drop
   >   Distance HD, Kingdom Hearts 0.2 Birth by Sleep -A Fragmentary
   >   Passage-, and the cutscenes for Kingdom Hearts X, titled as Kingdom
   >   Hearts X Back Cover. It will be released in Japan in 2016.

[image: Kingdom Hearts HD 2.8 Final Chapter Prologue Logo]

Comment: I had no idea they were releasing an HD remake of Dream Drop. Now, to wait, or just play the 3DS version. Choices, choices.

Comment: @Frank [they announced it yesterday at the TGS 2015](http://www.ign.com/articles/2015/09/15/tgs-2015-kingdom-hearts-28-final-chapter-prologue-announced)

Answer (score -1):

The Timeline order:

- Kingdom Hearts X Chi
- Kingdom Hearts Unchained X
- Kingdom Hearts X Back Cover
- Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep
- Kingdom Hearts
- Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories
- Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days
- Kingdom Hearts II
- Kingdom Hearts Coded
- Kingdom Hearts Dream Drop Distance
- Kingdom Hearts 0.2 Birth By Sleep
- Kingdom Hearts III

Recommended playing order:

- Kingdom Hearts
- Kingdom Hearts Chain of Memories
- Kingdom Hearts II
- Kingdom Hearts 358/2 Days
- Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep
- Kingdom Hearts Coded
- Kingdom Hearts Dream Drop Distance
- Kingdom Hearts 0.2 Birth By Sleep
- Kingdom Hearts X Chi
- Kingdom Hearts Unchained X
- Kingdom Hearts X Back Cover
- Kingdom Hearts III (although it is not out yet)

Answer (score -2):

Dude, if you play the core games alone (which I highly advise AGAINST it), and then jump right into Kingdom Hearts III when it comes out, you'll be as confused as a man learning Calculus in China. I'm pretty sure. Since Kingdom Hearts' storyline is so... ... there are no words.

I recommend you play the following:

- Kingdom Hearts X Chi
  (because KHx is a Japan-only browser game, you should play instead...)
- Kingdom Hearts Unchained X Chi

And while you're at it, I'd recommend watching the...

- Kingdom Hearts Back Cover

Both games' endings are similar, but do be careful at the start of watching Back Cover as it shows you events that will spoil Unchained X. So I'd watch it if I'm close to finishing (or finished) Unchained X.

Then...

- Kingdom Hearts Birth By Sleep
- Kingdom Hearts 0.2 Birth By Sleep
- Kingdom Hearts

Then play these games simultaneously.

- Kingdom Hearts Chain of memories
- Kingdom Hearts 358/2 days
- Kingdom Hearts 2
- Kingdom Hearts Re:Coded

And finally...

- Kingdom Hearts Dream Drop Distance

**0.2 Birth by Sleep is a Kingdom Hearts 2.8 exclusive**

Comment: The question was asking about the timeline of Kingdom Hearts games, that is, its ***chronological order***, **not** your recommended playing order. You're missing games.

Comment: It _**is**_ the chronological order, which I also recommend like most people here. I understand the question perfectly.

Comment: Curious how you are supposed to play 4 games simultaneously